# UpdatePanel and posting messages to other controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Can I use a ScriptManager control to register custom events to be used as an AsyncPostbackTrigger with an UpdatePanel?

Example:

```
<Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger  ControlID="ucTest"  EventName="CustomEvent" />
</Triggers>
```

Thanks

Comment: This might help you: http://forums.asp.net/t/1123812.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this example:

TextControl.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="TextControl.ascx.vb" Inherits="TextControl" %>
<asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" Text="Text" />
```

TextControl.ascx.vb

```
Partial Class TextControl
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

    Public Event ButtonClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As _
     System.EventArgs)

    Private Sub button1_onclick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As _
     System.EventArgs) Handles button1.Click

        RaiseEvent ButtonClick(sender, e)

    End Sub

End Class
```

ctrlPage.aspx (Where control is used)

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="ctrlPage.aspx.vb" Inherits="ctrlPage" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    Namespace="System.Web.UI" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<%@ Register Src="TextControl.ascx" TagName="wTextC" TagPrefix="uc1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="scr1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
    <uc1:wTextC ID="wMenu1" runat="server" />
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upd1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="" ID="label1"></asp:Label>
        </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="wMenu1" EventName="ButtonClick" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

ctrlPage.aspx.vb

```
Partial Class ctrlPage
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub wMenu1_ButtonClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles wMenu1.ButtonClick
        Me.label1.Text = ":)"
    End Sub   

End Class
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. You are using a standard event signature with EventArgs. I have a custom class that is passed as a paramater in the event I would like to register for the AsyncPostbackTrigger. Every time I load the control I get this error:  The 'OnEntityChange' event on associated control 'eddState' for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'udpFilterEntityMultiple' does not match the standard event handler signature.

Comment: I think I have figured it out. If I register an AsyncPostBackTrigger event with a void(object sender, EventArgs e) method signature then it works great. If I register an AsyncPostBackTrigger with a void(MyCustomObject e) method signature then I get the above error. I guess the UpdatePanel does not know how to handle the MyCustomObject class.

Comment: So the void(object sender, EventArgs e) signature is handling well the passing of your custom class?

Comment: Thanks, The EventArgs works well with my events regardless of the class in which the event is defined in. I just wanted to use a custom class in the delegate method associated with the event. I will search around for a way and fall back on the standard signature if need be. Also, thanks for the link above it may lead to a solution.

Comment: Check this for the custom event args delegate:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1543851.aspx